# java script Vertical news ticker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, news-ticker

I have an html snippet like this :

```
<div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="news">
<ul id="listticker">
 <li><b>"Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text used by designers from all over the world. While writing Lorem ipsum you dont need worry grammar about and splleing mistkae. You get complete freedome of writing anything you want. I love Lorem Ipsum so much. .</li>
 <li><b>"Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text used by designers from all over the world. While writing Lorem ipsum you dont need worry grammar about and splleing mistkae. You get complete freedome of writing anything you want. I love Lorem Ipsum so much. </li>
 <li><b>"Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text used by designers from all over the world. While writing Lorem ipsum you dont need worry grammar about and splleing mistkae. You get complete freedome of writing anything you want. I love Lorem Ipsum so much. . </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

where in i have called the news_ticker script like this

```
<script src="js/news_ticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the code for the ticker is following

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var first = 0;
    var speed = 800;
    var pause = 3500;

    function removeFirst() {
        first = $('ul#listticker li:first').html();
        $('ul#listticker li:first')
.animate({ opacity: 0, height: "0px" }, speed, 'linear', function () { $(this).remove(); });
        addLast(first);
    }

    function addLast(first) {
        last = '<li style="display:none">' + first + '</li>';
        $('ul#listticker').append(last)
        $('ul#listticker li:last')
.animate({ opacity: 1, height: "auto" }, speed)
.fadeIn('slow')
    }
        interval = setInterval(removeFirst, pause);
});
```

Why doesn't my ticker scroll at all?

Comment: I do see some scrolling here http://jsfiddle.net/NeR8Z/. Is that not the intended effect? Is there an error in console?

Comment: i just try in Jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/PVD7F/)

Comment: @loxxy..is there any other ways around to accomplish same task? it doesn't work in my web page.. works well in jsfiddle! tried all way around!!

Comment: @mmu Did you include jQuery? Do you have a live demo?

Comment: @mmu have a look at the source code of this page http://fiddle.jshell.net/NeR8Z/show/ & check differences. As Felix suggests, you might have missed jquery.

Comment: is it because i used $(document).ready(function () )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ticker works fine, maybe your version of jQuery library is old. I test it with jQuery v2.0.3

Comment: i did update the jQuery library and now it works fine.